# The Terminal Process "Terminated With Exit Code 2"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio, terminal

my terminal keeps shutting down after a few minutes, I cant use react due to this.

[The Terminal Process "Terminated With Exit Code 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NofAh.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

Found A Solution!

I don't really have a perfect fix for the problem, but here's what you can do,

install Windows Terminal; a terminal emulator that you can get on the Microsoft store.

```
now instead of using the main terminal from the vs code, open up the windows terminal,
```

Windows Terminal

```
cd and paste the directory, (you can do it by dragging the folder)
```

and now you can access the terminal from here, and it won't shut down.

Comment: Please mark as an answer if you think your own answer solved your question.